# How to encrypt/decrypt a MS word document in visual C++

Tags: encryption, ms-word

I need a simple,small and efficient program for the following thing to do.

1. A small interface to choose a file from my PC.
2. Press encrypt/De-crypt button to do select whichever you need.
3. If encrypt is pressed, generate a random key and encrypt with some algorithm based on that key.
4. If decrypt is pressed decrypt the file using some algorithm.

I am planning to do it in visual C++. Can anyone please suggest a small program in VC++ to do this? or please tell me the library name where I can get all the functions to do the above.

If you think that there is some better language or framework available to do instead of VC++, please suggest. Thanks. I would very much grateful to you for this help.

Comment: This feels like a "gief me teh codez plox!!11" question, but when you do get around to implementing it, for the love of all that is good, do not attempt to re-implement your own encryption scheme (especially do not re-write AES). You won't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Visually C++ can call clr code when compiled with these [options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Once you have done that, you can use  this [api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx) or the far more secure version that Microsoft published [here](http://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Security.Cryptography.AuthenticatedAesCng). I'd use the second because then you get authenticated encryption for free. Otherwise you need to hmac the data and check it on the other end, which is a pain. In either case, make sure you use a random IV each time ( by default when you instantiate aes in .net , it creates a random IV  so just use that). Prepend it to the message and retrieve it when you decrypt